# It's possible to save image to app’s own photo album without duplicate in Camera Roll?

Tags: iphone, ios, alassetslibrary

I am trying to save a photo taken from my app to app’s own photo album (solution here http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/).

But image is saved in the Camera Roll and then creates a link in my own album. It's possible to save image to app’s own photo album without duplicate in Camera Roll?

Thanks!

Comment: Your application have its documents directory in which you can store images. Check this example-> (http://www.friendlydeveloper.com/2010/02/using-nsfilemanager-to-save-an-image-to-or-loadremove-an-image-from-documents-directory-coding/) Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Hemang! But the photos must be in a unique photo album and can be seen in the iphone photo application.

Comment: okey! I got you. I make this my favorite :) Good luck.

Comment: You can save the images in document directory and can also fetch from documents directory wherever You want to use the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately this is not possible. The Photo-Library works in the way that every photo in an "own photo album" is only a reference to the actual photo that is saved to the Camera Roll.

Cheers,

Hendrik